# Creating and modifying new netcdf based on initial netcdf using xarray

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have an xarray dataset with foll. structure:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:           (N: 5, latitude: 360, longitude: 720, time: 27)
Coordinates:
  * latitude          (latitude) float64 89.75 89.25 88.75 88.25 87.75 87.25 ...
  * longitude         (longitude) float64 -179.8 -179.2 -178.8 -178.2 -177.8 ...
  * time              (time) float64 0.0 1.826e+03 3.652e+03 5.479e+03 ...
  * N                 (N) |S1 '1' '2' '3' '4' '5'
```

I want to copy a handle to this dataset and remove the coordinated named 'N'.

When I do this:

```
new_nc = hndl_nc.copy() 
new_nc.drop('N')
```

Subsequently, when I try to assign data to new variable in new_nc, it does not work:

```
new_nc['new_var'] = ...
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drop`, like most xarray methods, returns a new xarray object rather than modifying the orginal object in-place. So instead you should write
`new_nc = hdnl_nc.drop('N')`.

Alternatively, you could Python's `del` keyword: `del new_nc['N']`